# Visual Studio 2013 Unit Test with Async Task

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, async-await

I have created a TestProject within Visual Studio 2013. I can create sync tests and they work fine. When I try to use async it's not showing in the Test Explorer. I have seen other posts that say to make sure using async Task but I am:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    await Test1();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, 2, "Not the same");
}
```

I am targetting .NET 4 and using the Microsoft Async nuget to get the async capabilities. Could this be the reason it's not working? Otherwise am at a loss.

Comment: How is your code not working? Is the assertion not running or the test itself not running?

Comment: The test itself doesn't show in Test Explorer to even be run. If I make if public void, it shows up. If i make it public async void, it shows up (but doesn't work properly obviously). But as soon as I make it async Task, it disappears from the list of tests.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is a side effect of targeting .NET 4.0. You can try to create a .NET 4.5 unit test project, but I am not 100% sure that will work.

Comment: Can you run your visual studio as administrator and try? It solved my problem once.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of. I won't waste any more time on it then. Will have to roll my own test program. Main thing is I get some test coverage!

Comment: Sriram, changing to administrator made no difference but thanks for suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to update the target framework to .Net 4.5 and the test became visible. VS did warn me that the some nuget packages used by the project were targeted for older .NET versions so I may still have some issues but technically the answer to my question was that the async tests don't work on .NET 4.0 but do on .NET 4.5.